# How to render an array of functions (all of them return divs) recursively?

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I have a little problem with a recursion task that I found.

I have three functions that are stored in an array:

```
const One = () => <div>One</div>
const Two = () => <div>Two</div>
const Three = () => <div>Three</div>

const arr = [One, Two, Three]
```

Then I pass this array as a prop to another component in which I must write a recursive function to make **One** a parent of **Two*, and **Two** a parent of **Three**.

The HTML shopuld look like that:

```
<div class='App-box'>
  One
  <div class='App-box'>
    Two
    <div class='App-box'>
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to write a recursive function for an array for objects or nested arrays but this one I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your data into a recursive iteration as follows:

```js
const data = {
  obj: One,
  children: [{
    obj: Two,
    children: [{
      obj: Three
    }]
  }]
}

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <RecursiveComp {...data} />
  )
}
```

and the recursive component:

```js
const RecursiveComp = ({ obj, children }) => {
  const hasChildren = children && children.length

  return (
    <div className='App-box'>
      {obj}
      {hasChildren && children.map((item) => (
        <RecursiveComp key={children.obj} {...item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to change the variable "data", you can use this:

```js
const data = [
    <div>One</div>,
    <div>Two</div>,
    <div>Three</div>,
  ]

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <RecursiveComp {...data} />
  )
}
```

```js
const RecursiveComp = (data) => {

  const children = Object.values(data).slice(1)

  return (
    <div className="App-class">
      {data[0]}
      {(children.length > 0) && <RecursiveComp {...children} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default RecursiveComp
```

Comment: Ty for the answer! I know that one - the thing is I cannot modify the array I have :)

Comment: I updated the answer and there is no need to change the array in the new one.

Answer (score 1):

A non-recursive solution that returns an Array of React `Element`s, contained in a `Fragment`.

`slice` is used as `reverse` mutates the array.

```js
['One','Two','Three'].slice().reverse().reduce((acc,str)=>
    React.createElement('div',{key:str }, [str].concat(acc))
, undefined)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```